# Cannot connect to a SQL Server 2005 Analysis Services cube after installing SQL Server 2008 SP1

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap-cube

I've been developing an application that talks directly to an SSAS 2005 OLAP cube. Note that I also have SQL Server 2008 installed, so the other day I did a Windows Update and decided to include SQL Server 2008 SP1 in my update. After doing that, my SSAS 2005 cube is no longer accessible from my application.

I'm able to browse the data just fine within SQL Server 2005 BI Studio Manager, but I'm not able to connect to the cube from my application. Here is my connection string that used to work:

```
Data Source=localhost;Provider=msolap;Initial Catalog=Adventure Works DW
```

Here is the error message I get:

`Either the user, [Server]/[User], does not have access to the Adventure Works DW database, or the database does not exist.`

Here is the beginning of my stack trace if it would help:

`Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdErrorResponseException was unhandled by user code
  HelpLink=""
  Message="Either the user, Luc-PC\\Luc, does not have access to the Adventure Works DW database, or the database does not exist."
  Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Analysis Services"
  ErrorCode=-1055391743
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.IDiscoverProvider.Discover(String requestType, IDictionary restrictions, DataTable table)
       at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.ObjectMetadataCache.Discover(AdomdConnection connection, String requestType, ListDictionary restrictions, DataTable destinationTable, Boolean doCreate)
       at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.ObjectMetadataCache.PopulateSelf()
       at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.ObjectMetadataCache.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.IObjectCache.Populate()
       at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.CacheBasedNotFilteredCollection.PopulateCollection()
       at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.CacheBasedNotFilteredCollection.get_Count()
       at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.CubesEnumerator.MoveNext()
       at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.CubeCollection.Enumerator.MoveNext()
       at blah blah...`

I've looked for a solution for the last 4+ hours and haven't had any success. Thanks in advance for any help.

Luc

Comment: possible duplicate of [deployment of adventureworks cube fails: 'user does not have permission to create a new object in 'GARY-PC' or the object does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333567/deployment-of-adventureworks-cube-fails-user-does-not-have-permission-to-creat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by granting myself admin permissions on the cube. Right or wrong, it worked and I was able to move on...