# How to add an administrator user of sql server analysis services 2008 R2 after the install?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas

I use Sql Server 2008 R2 and SSAS.

After install SQL Server 2008 R2 i joind to domain .

And After Login with my domain user i can not restore database in SSAS.

I get an error windows with this message :

`database administrator or server administrator permissions are required to execute systemgetlogicalderives`.

i add my domain user to security in MSDB but it not work ?!?

when i login with local user it work.

How i can fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [deployment of adventureworks cube fails: 'user does not have permission to create a new object in 'GARY-PC' or the object does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333567/deployment-of-adventureworks-cube-fails-user-does-not-have-permission-to-creat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to connect to the analysis services instance using SQL server management studio (make sure you use the analysis services option on the connection dialog) as a user that already has administrative permissions on the SSAS instance (it should have asked for a user/group when you installed SSAS)

Then once you are connected, right click on the server, select properties, then security.  You can then add more users or groups to the server administrator role from here.

Comment: is there any way to do it by xmla script?